# How to get a column value from data table with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

How to get a column value from a data table object. I have the id column on which basis I am trying to get another column value.

e.g. ApplicationId is the primary key column which I have and now I want to get the xyz column value for this ApplicationId.

Comment: why do you want to use linq any way

Comment: I am manipulating grid values while grid is bound to the data table. Now when anything is changed from the grid, I have to check what was the previous value for a particular column.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have accomplished my result by making use of the following Linq statement

```
List<string> lstResult= (from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                          where table.Field<int>("Id") == id
                                          select table.Field<string>("status")).ToList();
```

string dtStatus = lstResult[0];

Comment: is there any version beside this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
var x= from myrow in myDataTable.asEnumerable() where myrow.ApplicationId==[YourValue] select myRow.[ColumnYouWant];
```

I am not great when it comes to linq but this should do the trick.

Comment: I have figured out another option which I am currently testing var result = from table in dt.AsEnumerable()
                                    where dt.Field<int>("Id") == ID
                                    select dt.Field<int>("Status");

Answer (score 0):

you can do it lik this

```
var results = (from  rows in dt.AsEnumerable() select new {resultcolumnname=row["resultcolumnname"]}).where(item=>item.columnname == value).ToList()
```